# How to build software that mimics topcoder, codingbat etc.?

Tags: java

I want to build a downloadable desktop software which shows the user a GUI with a sample problem.

[image]

The user then proceeds to code a solution and pastes it to a blank screen.

The program evaluates it and gives points to the user. The user progresses to the next level.

My question is, how do these sites evaluate a program for correctness? I don't mean to measure performance.

Do they write their own compiler or parse the text and feed it to javac and extract the output as well as search for some required keywords in the code.

Comment: I guess you would have to find someone who works at topcoder to be sure, but I would guess they just compile and test outputs against random inputs.

Comment: If you are limiting the application to Java source only, then the Java compiler API will be useful: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html

Comment: @redmave: I used to be a high-ranked yellow coder on TopCoder years ago...  Correctness is evaluated by a fixed set of inputs created by each problem's author **and** by also evaluating all the inputs submitted by the coders/competitors: there's a "phase" after submission where you can see everyone's answers and try to make them fail.  If you make someone else' answer fail, then you get bonus points.  If I recall correctly every single input used to test the problem is then published...  So, open an account on TopCoder and see how it works.

Comment: @redmave: btw correctness of user submitted inputs is done by checking them against a known-correct reference implementation solving the problem.  Very rarely does the reference implementation have a bug.  In that case it is rewritten and points/results are re-computed once the correct implementation is out.  It is **really** for "top coders".  Companies like Google and Yahoo! kept using their services in the past to hire bright minds...

Answer (score 1):

You should compile the code with the standard compiler and then run the program, feeding it with pre-defined (or dynamically generated) inputs and verify that the output is the same as those from a known working solution that was provided by the problem's creator.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem statement always has well defined input and output formats.
You should:

- compile the code
- run it with your input
- get the output
- compare it with YOUR output (which has the correct answers for the program)

Notice that YOU have the inputs and the correct output.

Also, notice that you can use `diff`, which is a unix program that takes 2 files and outputs the differences (having anything in the output of diff means that the program was not correct).

Also, notice that you should set a timeout for the program and sanitize it. This can be done by disallowing some libraries and system calls (write a program that looks for them in the code, it's not hard).

Hope that helps.